# Stylesheet for .html document not imported

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have this form I created in HTML (called form.html) written in google apps script and I also have a stylesheet (CSS) to go with that. All is working well when I have the CSS in the same HTML-file as the form. However if I want to put my stylesheet in a separate HTML-file (called Stylesheet.html) and then include it in the form.html by using a scriplet

```
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Stylesheet').getContent(); ?>
```

or even creating an 'include' function:

```
function include(filename) {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .getContent();
  }
```

and then in form.html

```
<?!= include(Stylesheet) ?>
```

..it doesn't seem to work. What's even worse the scriplet shows up on the form. 
Maybe there is something basic I am overlooking, but I can't wrap my head around this. Any ideas ?

**Here is the code so far...**

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Formulier')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .getContent();
}

function materiaalLijst(afdnum) {
 return SpreadsheetApp.openById('1l6MKG61GHMFSZrOg04W4KChpb7oZBU9VKp42FPXmldc')
        .getSheetByName('RESERVATIE')
        .getDataRange()
        .getValues()
        .map(function (v) {
            return v[Number(afdnum) - 1]
        })
        .splice(1);
 }


//work in progress
function processForm(form) {
    Logger (form); //array containing form elements
}
```

```css
<style>

form {
    /* Just to center the form on the page */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    /* To see the outline of the form */
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 1em;
}


form div + div {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
label {
    /* To make sure that all labels have the same size and are properly aligned */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
    text-align: right;
}

input, textarea {
    /* To make sure that all text fields have the same font settings
       By default, textareas have a monospace font */
    font: 1em sans-serif;

    /* To give the same size to all text field */
    width: 300px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    /* To harmonize the look & feel of text field border */
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
    /* To give a little highlight on active elements */
    border-color: #000;
}

textarea {
    /* To properly align multiline text fields with their labels */
    vertical-align: top;

    /* To give enough room to type some text */
    height: 5em;

    /* To allow users to resize any textarea vertically
       It does not work on every browsers */
    resize: vertical;
}

</style>
```

```html
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Stylesheet').getContent(); ?>


<form id="myForm">
    <!-- Text input field -->
    <div>
        <label for="name">Naam:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Voornaam + naam" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Afdeling">Afdeling:</label>
        <input type="radio" id="1" name="Afd" value="Oostende">Oostende
        <input type="radio" id="2" name="Afd" value="Brugge">Brugge
        <input type="radio" id="3" name="Afd" value="Westhoek">Westhoek
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="datepicker">Datum:</label>
        <input type="date" id="resdatum" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="timepicker">Uur:</label>
        <input type="time" id="restijd" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Frequentie">Frequentie:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="freq" value="éénmalig" required>éénmalig
        <input type="radio" name="freq" value="meermaals">voor meerdere weken
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Materiaal">Materiaal:</label>
        <select id="materiaal" name="materiaalselectie" required>
            <option value="notSel">Kies..</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- The submit button. It calls the server side function uploadfiles() on click -->
        <input type="submit" id="verzenden" name="verzenden" class="verzenden" value="Reservatie verzenden" >
    </div>
    
    <div id="output"></div>

</form>

 <div id="output"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    

    $("input:radio[name=Afd]").click(function() {
        go(this.id);
    });

    function go(idAfd) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showList).materiaalLijst(idAfd);
    }

    function showList(things) {
        var list = $('#materiaal');
        list.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
            list.append('<option value="' + things[i] + '">' + things[i] + '</option>');
        }
    }

 //below is work in progress...
 
   $('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
   var arr =[];
   
     //var fields = $( ":input" ).serializeArray();
    $.each( $( ":input" ).serializeArray(), function( i, field ) {
      arr.push( field.value);
    });
    var json = JSON.stringify($('#myForm').serializeArray());
    google.script.run.processForm(arr);
    alert(arr);
    })
 
   
</script>
```

The result with CSS ***IN*** the form.html

[image: css in form.html]

and here is the CSS in a separate .html file and included
in form.html with

```
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Stylesheet').getContent(); ?>
```

[image: CSS on Stylesheet.html]

Comment: Be sure to include <style>. </style> at the beginning and the end of your stylesheet.html file

Comment: @ScampMichael: I did.. :-(

Comment: Note: If the "scoped" attribute is not used, each <style> tag must be located in the head section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You're doing this right:**

Your css file must be an HTML file, as those are the only type supported by `HtmlService`. If you look at the starter scripts, you'll find that they have `Stylesheet.html`, with content:

```
<!-- This CSS package applies Google styling; it should always be included. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<style>
...
</style>
```

You know the google css is working if your sidebar or dialog looks pretty much like google stuff - same font, same text size. To have an action button be blue, you need to add the appropriate class to it, `class="action"`.

**Why isn't yours working?**
<sup><sub>Get ready for a face-palm moment...</sub></sup>

You're using scriptlets, part of the Html Service templated HTML. They require interpretation, which is not done by `HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile()`. (That's why you see the scriptlet line literally.)

Instead, you need to read the file containing scriptlets as a *template*, and then `.evaluate()` it.

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

To display the google-themed action button, include the Apps Script CSS and add "action" class:

```
<input type="submit" id="verzenden" name="verzenden" class="action verzenden" value="Reservatie verzenden" >
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: that's what I commented on the previous answer. So it is a html-file. That google styling I tried also. How to tell if it works ? E.g should a button be colored blue then ? If so, is is not working either.. Could an extension be blocking that content ?

Comment: Updated answer. But you don't have enough info in your question - no HTML for example. So, I'm guessing. An extension _could_ be doing almost anything - what extension are you talking about?

Comment: I was just thinking out loud (desperately seeking for an explanation. I disabled all extensions bu to no avail apparently.. I included code and screenshot in the question.

Comment: a face-palm moment indeed... Don't know how I missed that, but a very valuable lesson learned. Thanks a bunch for helping me out.

Comment: Exactly the sort of problem many folks will encounter as they improve already-working scripts. Great question!

Answer (score -1):

How about to name it Stylesheet.css?
And try to include it via normal HTML in the header.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
```

HTH

Comment: When I click 'new' in the Google Apps script editor and can choose 'Project', 'Script File' or 'HTML-file'. 'CSS-file' is simply not an option. But still it should work, as it is described in 'best practices' over here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices

Comment: No, that's wrong. This answer is COMPLETELY WRONG for Google Apps Script. There is no local CSS hosting, so the href provided will not work. You _could_ link to any externally hosted css, so for this answer to make sense the OP would also need to address the hosting issue.